# Loops in SQL? Or can looping always be done with set functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to find out what is the 0-30 day revenue for each new user given the following table structure. Would like to exclude any revenue past 30 days.

`Table A` has two attributes: `id` and `createdate`. This is the users table where every new user get put into here on his createdate.
`Table B` has three attributes: `userid`, `revenue`, and `orderdate`. This table logs every order that happens on the orderdate.

My knowledge of SQL is really rusty so the only way I can think of doing this is with a loop. But if I remember anything from my databases class, it was to never use loops. What do you all think?

Comment: +1 for the *"If I remember anything from my databases class ..."*

Comment: What is a 0-30 day revenue? Can you add a few rows for the 2 tables and the expected result?

Comment: 0-30 day revenue means each user's revenue from day 0 to day 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done without a loop:

```
   SELECT a.id AS userid,
          SUM(b.revenue) AS revenue
     FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
       ON a.id = b.userid
    WHERE (b.orderdate - a.createdate) < 2592000
       OR (b.orderdate - a.createdate) IS NULL
 GROUP BY a.id
```

2592000 is 30 days in seconds - I'm assuming you are using unix timestamps as your date fields.

Comment: Why would one use Unix timestamps for storing dates when there is a `DATE` datatype?

Comment: Why are you subtracting createdate from oderdate? This will return the revenue of each user's _first_ 30 days, not the entire store's most recent 30 days. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yup, exactly, each user's first 30 days is the metrics that is most interesting.  It pretty much standardizes a look at revenue.  Thanks much!!

Comment: Did you realise that the where clause effectively turns the left join into an inner join?

Comment: @David Souther That was my interpretation of '0-30 day revenue' in the question (which turned out to be correct).

Comment: @Mark Bannister Good catch. I missed out the OR (b.orderdate - a.createdate) IS NULL clause, that was necessary. I have edited to add it.

Comment: @ypercube Just a habit - the systems I work with mostly use timestamps, so without any indication to the contrary I used that convention. It works just the same if you use the date functions of course, as David Souther demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look at your particular database for the datetime syntax, but in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(revenue) as month_revenue
FROM b
WHERE orderdate > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS)
```

[Edit]

That was just for a single user, using table b. To do a complete query across both tables, we'll be a bit more exotic.

```
SELECT a.id as userid, SUM(b.revenue) as revenue
FROM a
INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.userid
WHERE orderdate > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS)
GROUP BY a.id
```

We are doing a join on the two tables, so we get a virtual table with structure `(id, createdate, userid, revenue, orderdate)` and one record for each entry in **b**. The WHERE is self explanatory, except to point out that it is there. The GROUP BY separates those into the distinct userids, and the sum works on those groups.

Comment: I think an `INNER JOIN` would be more appropriate. Your clause `WHERE OrderDate > ...` will remove any records where b.OrderDate IS NULL effectively limiting the left join to an inner join. Since inner joins perform better than left joins it seems logical to make the switch. Unless you want to include users with no orders in which case the `WHERE` clause needs to be moved to the `JOIN` clause. As in Mark Bannister's answer.

Comment: @GarethD Good point. I use left joins as my default go-to when first writing a query, but yes, had I thought it through, inner joins are the better tool here.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select a.id, sum(b.revenue) `0-30 days revenue`
from a
left join b on a.id = b.userid and 
               b.orderdate <= date_add(a.createdate, interval 30 day)
group by a.id
```